# Standardizing font-weight between OSX and Windows

Tags: html, css, windows, macos, webfonts

I've read that OSX and Windows have two very different algorithms for rendering fonts. As such, it's a common issue that web fonts look "heavier" when viewing them in OSX than they do in Windows.

For example, this is the same font, on the same site, in the same browser, but on different operating systems:

[image]

Here's Arial exhibiting similar differences:

[image]

Is there any way of altering the rendering of fonts in either Windows or OSX so they look closer to each other? Or is there some other technique to deal with this difference?

Comment: The best you cna o is work around it and dont use different weights/styles unless you are explicitly using the fontface for the weight style (ie. MyFont, MyFont Bold, MyFont Heavy, MyFont Italic, etc.).

Comment: There is a couple ways to change the rendering of fonts for yourself but I don't know of anything for coder/developper to make their page adjust people operating system

Comment: The examples look like cases of actual font weight being different, rather than usual font rendering differences. Please provide actual codes and/or URLs that produce these differences.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela They're not differences in font weights. I have checked them all in Developer Tools. Everything has the font-weight set to "normal" or "400". I can't supply a 2000+ line CSS file (WP). If you want to see this for yourself, though, you can easily log into any Wordpress site for the second example.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That font is a particularly bad example, I deal with a lot of fonts and have never seen one look like that. Keep in mind that people are used to seeing their fonts rendered a certain way on their own machines, and thus it is *not* your job to dictate how fonts should be rendered.

A few things to keep in mind are to only use weights you've included, for example, do not use `font-weight: bold` on a custom font-face if you haven't actually included the bold version of that font. "Browser bold" always looks messed up compared to the actual bold font.

Also, for some fonts, I find that I need to change the font-smoothing property for webkit browsers, as the default (subpixel-aliased) can look a little heavy. You can add this property to any element that uses the problematic font (even the body, if required).

```
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
```

Comment: Some good tips here. (The font is rendered "Normal", not "Bold".) Unfortunately it's the client who thinks the font looks too bold in OSX -- and to be honest I can't disagree! I'll try your webkit trick, though, see if it helps.

Comment: what if I want to use OSX rendering in windows not the opposite (antialiasing)

Comment: @snake There are three properties for `-webkit-font-smoothing`. `none`, `antialiased`, and `subpixel-antialiased`. Other than that, everything I wrote in my answer stands true. You cannot control the way fonts are rendered on other people's machines.